# java spark logging level issue with spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, apache-spark

I am using spark with java spring boot, want to set log level ERROR to console and file, but it's not working, tried the following solution

1)`.set("spark.executor.extraJavaOptions","-Dlog4jspark.root.logger=ERROR,console")`
2)`.set("spark.driver.extraJavaOptions", "-Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel=ERROR,console")`

3. `spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel('ERROR')`

but not working :(

**spark configuration:**

[image]

**pom.xml Dependancy:**

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
        <version>${scala.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-compiler</artifactId>
        <version>${scala.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-reflect</artifactId>
        <version>${scala.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    
        <!-- For spring MVC -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
           <exclusion>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
        </exclusions> 
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- For Spring Integration -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-integration</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-mllib_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/log4j-over-slf4j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.4</version>
    </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-beanutils-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.39</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
        <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.24-incubating</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-beanutils-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
                <artifactId>hadoop-yarn-common</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.189</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>            
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-beanutils-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
                <artifactId>hadoop-yarn-common</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>*</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.17</version>
    </dependency>       
    <dependency> 
        <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId> 
        <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId> 
        <version>4.1</version> 
    </dependency> 

    <!--Test-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
        <artifactId>scalatest_${scala.libversion}</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.healthmarketscience.sqlbuilder/sqlbuilder -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.healthmarketscience.sqlbuilder</groupId>
        <artifactId>sqlbuilder</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>ca.krasnay</groupId>
      <artifactId>sqlbuilder</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.crealytics</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-excel_2.10</artifactId>
      <version>0.8.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.eclipsesource.minimal-json</groupId>
      <artifactId>minimal-json</artifactId>
      <version>0.9.5</version>
    </dependency>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/joda-time/joda-time -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: If you downgrade spring version to 1.5.9.RELEASE, it will work fine

Answer (score 1):

In the application.properties that you should have in the src/main/resources, add:

logging.level.org.apache=WARN

Hope it works

Answer (score 0):

For my current configuration:

- Spring Boot: 2.2.1.RELEASE
- Spark: 2.12

I exclude Log4j as you've done.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.12</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.core.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Then you should configure logback.xml in the resource folder:

```
<configuration>

<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
        <pattern>
            %d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} %magenta([%thread]) %highlight(%-5level) %logger{36}.%M - %msg%n
        </pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<logger name="org.apache.spark" level="WARN"/>

<root level="info">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
</root>
```

Edit this logger level `<logger name="org.apache.spark" level="WARN"/>` to configure logging for Spark.