# Spring Boot Logging to a File

Tags: java, spring, logging

In my application config i have defined the following properties:

```
logging.file.name  = application.logs
```

When i run my application it's creating two files `application.logs.0` and `application.logs.0.lck` and the content of file as follow

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE log SYSTEM "logger.dtd">
<log>
<record>
  <date>2022-02-16T12:55:05.656986Z</date>
  <millis>1645016105656</millis>
  <nanos>986000</nanos>
  <sequence>0</sequence>
  <logger>org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService</logger>
  <level>INFO</level>
  <class>org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService</class>
  <method>startInternal</method>
  <thread>1</thread>
  <message>Starting service [Tomcat]</message>
</record>
<record>
  <date>2022-02-16T12:55:05.671696Z</date>
  <millis>1645016105671</millis>
  <nanos>696000</nanos>
  <sequence>1</sequence>
  <logger>org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine</logger>
  <level>INFO</level>
  <class>org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine</class>
  <method>startInternal</method>
  <thread>1</thread>
  <message>Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.48]</message>
</record>
```

It's not properly printing logs and don't want to output in the xml format

My Dependency Tree:

```
[INFO] com.walmart.uss:trigger:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- com.google.cloud:google-cloud-logging:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:31.0.1-jre:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.guava:failureaccess:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.guava:listenablefuture:jar:9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:3.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.checkerframework:checker-qual:jar:3.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:jar:2.8.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.j2objc:j2objc-annotations:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.grpc:grpc-api:jar:1.41.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.grpc:grpc-context:jar:1.41.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.grpc:grpc-stub:jar:1.41.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.grpc:grpc-protobuf:jar:1.41.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.grpc:grpc-protobuf-lite:jar:1.41.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.api:api-common:jar:2.0.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.auto.value:auto-value-annotations:jar:1.8.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:jar:3.18.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java-util:jar:3.18.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.8.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:jar:2.6.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-cloud-logging-v2:jar:0.92.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.api:gax:jar:2.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.opencensus:opencensus-api:jar:0.28.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.api:gax-grpc:jar:2.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.grpc:grpc-auth:jar:1.41.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.auth:google-auth-library-credentials:jar:1.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.grpc:grpc-netty-shaded:jar:1.41.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.grpc:grpc-alts:jar:1.41.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.grpc:grpc-grpclb:jar:1.41.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.conscrypt:conscrypt-openjdk-uber:jar:2.5.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.threeten:threetenbp:jar:1.5.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.cloud:google-cloud-core-grpc:jar:2.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.auth:google-auth-library-oauth2-http:jar:1.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:jar:1.40.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.http-client:google-http-client:jar:1.40.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.15:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.14:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.opencensus:opencensus-contrib-http-util:jar:0.28.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.grpc:grpc-core:jar:1.41.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.android:annotations:jar:4.1.1.4:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.mojo:animal-sniffer-annotations:jar:1.20:runtime
[INFO] |  +- io.perfmark:perfmark-api:jar:0.23.0:runtime
[INFO] |  +- com.google.cloud:google-cloud-core:jar:2.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-iam-v1:jar:1.1.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.5.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.5.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.5.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:jar:1.3.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.3.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.3.8:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.28:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:2.5.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:2.5.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:2.5.2:test
[INFO] |  +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.5.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.4.7:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:2.4.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:jar:2.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:jar:1.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:3.19.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest:jar:2.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:jar:5.7.2:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:jar:5.7.2:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:jar:1.1.0:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.opentest4j:opentest4j:jar:1.2.0:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:jar:1.7.2:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:jar:5.7.2:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:jar:5.7.2:test
[INFO] |  |     \- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-engine:jar:1.7.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:3.9.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.10.22:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:jar:1.10.22:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:3.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:jar:3.9.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.5.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- com.vaadin.external.google:android-json:jar:0.0.20131108.vaadin1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:5.3.8:test
[INFO] |  \- org.xmlunit:xmlunit-core:jar:2.8.2:test
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf:jar:2.5.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-spring5:jar:3.0.12.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf:jar:3.0.12.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.attoparser:attoparser:jar:2.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.unbescape:unbescape:jar:1.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-java8time:jar:3.0.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:5.3.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.3.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.3.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.3.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.3.8:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.3.8:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:jar:2.5.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:5.5.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:5.5.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-crypto:jar:5.5.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:5.5.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:2.5.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:2.5.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:5.3.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:5.3.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:5.3.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.9.6:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.31:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:2.5.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:2.5.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.9.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:2.5.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.zaxxer:HikariCP:jar:4.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- jakarta.transaction:jakarta.transaction-api:jar:1.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- jakarta.persistence:jakarta.persistence-api:jar:2.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.4.32.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.4.2.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.27.0-GA:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss:jandex:jar:2.2.3.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.5.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.dom4j:dom4j:jar:2.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:5.1.2.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:jar:2.3.4:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.glassfish.jaxb:txw2:jar:2.3.4:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- com.sun.istack:istack-commons-runtime:jar:3.0.12:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- com.sun.activation:jakarta.activation:jar:1.2.2:runtime
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:5.3.8:compile
[INFO] +- org.projectlombok:lombok:jar:1.18.12:provided
[INFO] +- com.h2database:h2:jar:1.4.190:runtime
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:2.5.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:jar:2.5.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:jar:2.12.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.12.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:jar:2.12.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:2.5.2:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:9.0.48:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:9.0.48:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:9.0.48:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.12:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-core:jar:5.5.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-messaging:jar:5.3.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.retry:spring-retry:jar:1.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- io.projectreactor:reactor-core:jar:3.4.7:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:jar:1.0.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-text:jar:1.9:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.12.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.12.3:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.12.3:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.12.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:jar:2.5.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure:jar:2.5.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator:jar:2.5.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- io.micrometer:micrometer-core:jar:1.7.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.hdrhistogram:HdrHistogram:jar:2.1.12:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.latencyutils:LatencyUtils:jar:2.0.3:runtime
[INFO] +- org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:jar:3.8.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-inject-plexus:jar:1.4.2:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-inject-bean:jar:1.4.2:compile
[INFO] |  |        \- org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-guice:jar:noaop:2.1.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:2.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-core:jar:3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-settings-builder:jar:3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-model-builder:jar:3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-aether-provider:jar:3.0:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- org.sonatype.aether:aether-impl:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.sonatype.aether:aether-spi:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.sonatype.aether:aether-api:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.sonatype.aether:aether-util:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interpolation:jar:1.14:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-classworlds:jar:2.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-component-annotations:jar:1.5.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-sec-dispatcher:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-cipher:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.maven.shared:maven-shared-utils:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.maven.shared:maven-shared-incremental:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-java:jar:0.9.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:6.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.thoughtworks.qdox:qdox:jar:2.0-M8:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-compiler-api:jar:2.8.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-compiler-manager:jar:2.8.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-compiler-javac:jar:2.8.4:runtime
[INFO] +- org.postgresql:postgresql:jar:42.2.23:compile
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
[INFO] |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:2.2:test
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-loader:jar:2.5.6:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.cloud:google-cloud-dataproc:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-cloud-dataproc-v1:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] +- mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:8.0.25:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.cloud:google-cloud-bigquery:jar:2.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.cloud:google-cloud-core-http:jar:2.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.api-client:google-api-client:jar:1.32.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client:jar:1.32.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.http-client:google-http-client-apache-v2:jar:1.40.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.http-client:google-http-client-appengine:jar:1.40.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.api:gax-httpjson:jar:0.91.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.http-client:google-http-client-jackson2:jar:1.40.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.checkerframework:checker-compat-qual:jar:2.5.5:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.google.apis:google-api-services-bigquery:jar:v2-rev20211017-1.32.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.12:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.thoughtworks.paranamer:paranamer:jar:2.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.avro:avro:jar:1.8.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.8.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.tukaani:xz:jar:1.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.avro:avro-mapred:jar:hadoop2:1.8.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.avro:avro-ipc:jar:1.8.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.twitter:chill_2.12:jar:0.9.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.esotericsoftware:kryo-shaded:jar:4.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- com.esotericsoftware:minlog:jar:1.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.twitter:chill-java:jar:0.9.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.xbean:xbean-asm7-shaded:jar:4.15:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-client:jar:3.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common:jar:3.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:jar:9.4.42.v20210604:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-security:jar:9.4.42.v20210604:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util-ajax:jar:9.4.42.v20210604:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- javax.servlet.jsp:jsp-api:jar:2.1:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.9.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-configuration2:jar:2.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.google.re2j:re2j:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-auth:jar:3.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- com.nimbusds:nimbus-jose-jwt:jar:9.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |     \- com.github.stephenc.jcip:jcip-annotations:jar:1.0-1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.curator:curator-client:jar:2.12.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.htrace:htrace-core4:jar:4.1.0-incubating:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.kerby:kerb-simplekdc:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.apache.kerby:kerb-client:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  +- org.apache.kerby:kerby-config:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  +- org.apache.kerby:kerb-core:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  |  \- org.apache.kerby:kerby-pkix:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  |     +- org.apache.kerby:kerby-asn1:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  |     \- org.apache.kerby:kerby-util:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  +- org.apache.kerby:kerb-common:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  |  \- org.apache.kerby:kerb-crypto:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  +- org.apache.kerby:kerb-util:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  \- org.apache.kerby:token-provider:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.apache.kerby:kerb-admin:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |     +- org.apache.kerby:kerb-server:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |     |  \- org.apache.kerby:kerb-identity:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |     \- org.apache.kerby:kerby-xdr:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:jar:3.1.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.fasterxml.woodstox:woodstox-core:jar:5.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- dnsjava:dnsjava:jar:2.1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-hdfs-client:jar:3.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:jar:2.7.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- com.squareup.okio:okio:jar:1.6.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-yarn-api:jar:3.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- javax.activation:javax.activation-api:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-yarn-client:jar:3.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-mapreduce-client-core:jar:3.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-yarn-common:jar:3.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:4.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:jar:9.4.42.v20210604:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jaxb-annotations:jar:2.12.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-json-provider:jar:2.12.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |        \- com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-base:jar:2.12.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient:jar:3.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-mapreduce-client-common:jar:3.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-annotations:jar:3.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.spark:spark-launcher_2.12:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.spark:spark-kvstore_2.12:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.fusesource.leveldbjni:leveldbjni-all:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.spark:spark-network-common_2.12:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.spark:spark-network-shuffle_2.12:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.spark:spark-unsafe_2.12:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.curator:curator-recipes:jar:2.13.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.curator:curator-framework:jar:2.13.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.zookeeper:zookeeper:jar:3.4.14:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.yetus:audience-annotations:jar:0.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- jakarta.servlet:jakarta.servlet-api:jar:4.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-math3:jar:3.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.31:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.31:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.ning:compress-lzf:jar:1.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.xerial.snappy:snappy-java:jar:1.1.8.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.lz4:lz4-java:jar:1.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.github.luben:zstd-jni:jar:1.4.8-1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.roaringbitmap:RoaringBitmap:jar:0.9.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.roaringbitmap:shims:jar:0.9.0:runtime
[INFO] |  +- commons-net:commons-net:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.scala-lang.modules:scala-xml_2.12:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.scala-lang:scala-library:jar:2.12.10:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:jar:2.12.10:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.json4s:json4s-jackson_2.12:jar:3.7.0-M5:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.json4s:json4s-core_2.12:jar:3.7.0-M5:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.json4s:json4s-ast_2.12:jar:3.7.0-M5:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.json4s:json4s-scalap_2.12:jar:3.7.0-M5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:jar:2.33:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- jakarta.ws.rs:jakarta.ws.rs-api:jar:2.1.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.glassfish.hk2.external:jakarta.inject:jar:2.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common:jar:2.33:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.glassfish.hk2:osgi-resource-locator:jar:1.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-server:jar:2.33:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- jakarta.validation:jakarta.validation-api:jar:2.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet:jar:2.33:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet-core:jar:2.33:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.inject:jersey-hk2:jar:2.33:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-locator:jar:2.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.glassfish.hk2.external:aopalliance-repackaged:jar:2.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-api:jar:2.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-utils:jar:2.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.netty:netty-all:jar:4.1.65.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.clearspring.analytics:stream:jar:2.9.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-core:jar:4.1.24:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-jvm:jar:4.1.24:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-json:jar:4.1.24:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-graphite:jar:4.1.24:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-jmx:jar:4.1.24:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-scala_2.12:jar:2.12.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.ivy:ivy:jar:2.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- oro:oro:jar:2.0.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.razorvine:pyrolite:jar:4.30:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.sf.py4j:py4j:jar:0.10.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.spark:spark-tags_2.12:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-crypto:jar:1.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.spark-project.spark:unused:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.spark:spark-streaming_2.12:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.12:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.spark:spark-token-provider-kafka-0-10_2.12:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:jar:2.7.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.spark:spark-avro_2.12:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-pool2:jar:2.9.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.codehaus.janino:janino:jar:3.0.8:compile
[INFO] +- org.codehaus.janino:commons-compiler:jar:3.0.8:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.spark:spark-sql_2.12:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.univocity:univocity-parsers:jar:2.9.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.spark:spark-sketch_2.12:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.spark:spark-catalyst_2.12:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.scala-lang.modules:scala-parser-combinators_2.12:jar:1.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.antlr:antlr4-runtime:jar:4.8-1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.arrow:arrow-vector:jar:2.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.arrow:arrow-format:jar:2.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.arrow:arrow-memory-core:jar:2.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.google.flatbuffers:flatbuffers-java:jar:1.9.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.arrow:arrow-memory-netty:jar:2.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.orc:orc-core:jar:1.5.12:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.orc:orc-shims:jar:1.5.12:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.airlift:aircompressor:jar:0.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.threeten:threeten-extra:jar:1.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.orc:orc-mapreduce:jar:1.5.12:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.hive:hive-storage-api:jar:2.7.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.parquet:parquet-column:jar:1.10.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.parquet:parquet-common:jar:1.10.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.parquet:parquet-encoding:jar:1.10.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.parquet:parquet-hadoop:jar:1.10.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.apache.parquet:parquet-format:jar:2.4.0:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.apache.parquet:parquet-jackson:jar:1.10.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka:jar:2.8.2:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.cloud:google-cloud-storage:jar:2.1.9:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.google.apis:google-api-services-storage:jar:v1-rev20210918-1.32.1:compile
[INFO] \- za.co.absa:abris_2.12:jar:6.0.0:compile
[INFO]    +- io.confluent:kafka-avro-serializer:jar:6.2.1:compile
[INFO]    |  +- io.confluent:kafka-schema-serializer:jar:6.2.1:compile
[INFO]    |  \- io.confluent:common-utils:jar:6.2.1:compile
[INFO]    +- io.confluent:kafka-schema-registry-client:jar:6.2.1:compile
[INFO]    |  +- io.swagger:swagger-annotations:jar:1.6.2:compile
[INFO]    |  \- io.swagger:swagger-core:jar:1.6.2:compile
[INFO]    |     +- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml:jar:2.12.3:compile
[INFO]    |     \- io.swagger:swagger-models:jar:1.6.2:compile
[INFO]    \- za.co.absa.commons:commons_2.12:jar:1.0.0:compile
```

My Spark Integration with Spring boot is causing the issue, i am not able to dependency which is causing it

Comment: Probably you have a log configuration file somewhere.

Comment: I don't have log file anywhere and also not sure why it's appending `0` and creating lock file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**application.logs.0.lck** is created for avoiding having corrupt data, you could have more than two logger instances trying to write the same log file and the result of it might not be the desired one.

You could try this to get a simple format of the log files:

```
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
```

Or:

```
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = org.springframework.boot.logging.java.SimpleFormatter
```

Comment: I think the issue is with Spark Lib which i have integrate in my projected i am not able to see any conflict dependency, udpated the maven tree

Comment: @Marcin_S Oh I see, You could try this configuration in Maven dependencies to exclude log4j from Spark. See this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/59195319/6292875

Answer (score 0):

Acording to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51236918/16651073
tomcat falls back to default logging if it can resolve the location

Can you try to save the properties without the spaces.

Like this:
`logging.file.name=application.logs`

Comment: log file is created, it's showing in correct format

Comment: @Marcin_S Perfect, could you mark my answer as accepted? :)

Comment: ohh sorry :) i misspelled it logs file is already create before but not in correct format see my comments